# Electrolysis of a solution of $\rm Ni(NO_3)_2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

This is a problem given in my textbook

> A current of $3.7 amp$ is passed for 6 hours between inert electrodes in 0.5 litres of 2M solution of $\rm Ni(NO_3)_2$. What will be molarity of the solution wrt $Ni2+$ at end of electrolysis.

The textbook straight away applies Faraday's law to calculate the equivalents of $Ni 2+$ reduced. But is it true? Cause the electrolysis is being carried out in an aqueous solution so there are $H+$ ions as well so by preferential discharge theory $H+$ should be reduced first. Now it may be said that since water is a weak electrolyte it doesn't ionise much so there aren't much $H+$ around but from what I have studied in Chemistry dissociation of water is an equilibrium process. So at any time $H2O$  is feebly ionised and unter neutral condition concentration of $H+$ is around $1/10^7$. So when the ionised $H+$ gets reduced at the cathode shouldn't the equilibrium be driven forward by Le Chatlier's principle thus more $H+$ being produced and the process looping itself?

Comment: There are 3 ignored things: 1/ Using the full Nernst equation instead of just standard redox potentials 2/ Considering respective ion activities 3/ Considering eventual hydrogen overpotential.

Comment: You can use `$\require{mhchem}$`  $\require{mhchem}$ to enable the optional mhchem MathJax package, enabled by default in chemistry SE. Then you can use e.g. `$\ce{Ni(NO3)2}$` to display $\ce{Ni(NO3)2}$, or `$\ce{Ni^2+}$` to display $\ce{Ni^2+}$. // See also [Formatting of chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)